# Remove sub list from super list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a newsletter subscriber list, with columns:

`company name, phone, email address, firstname, lastname, position`

I want to remove all duplicates in a second list from the first list. The second list has the same column layout.

The common factor would be the `email address`.

How do I do this please?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you wish to remove all duplicate instances**

Copy everything to the "second list" to work on.

Assuming `company name` on column A until `position` on column F.  In cell G2, insert the formula

```
=COUNTIF($C:$C,C2)
```

This formula counts how many instances are there, i.e. all duplicated rows will have the `COUNTIF` returning more than 1.  Apply a quick filter to select those rows with column G more than 1.  Delete those rows, and delete column G to cleanup and it is done.

**If you wish to leave one of the duplicate instances**

Copy everything to the "second list", select all cells in the second list, and then select from the ribbon `DATA -> Data Tools -> Remove Duplicates`.
[image]

Select column "email address" only.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Kenneth. Doesn't this only remove the 2nd instance of two? I want to remove both instances, so that I subtract the 2nd list from the 1st.

Comment: I misunderstood your question and revised the answer.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest two methods.*

**Method 1:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- *Write this formula in Cell `H254` & fill down:*

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C254,$C$247:$C$249,0)),"Unique","Duplicate")`

- Select List 2 range `A254:H257`.
- From **Data Tab** hit **Filter** and Filter **Duplicates**.
- Finally from **Home Tab** select **Delete** then **Delete Sheet
  Row**.

**Note,** Excel will Delete all Filtered Rows from List 2, have text DUPLICATE 
          in Col H.

**Method 2:**

- Press `Alt+F11` to open VB editor.
- Select  **VIEW** menu and click **Immediate Window**.
- Write this VB code in Immediate Window & finish with **Enter
  button**.

  `Range("A247:F257").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=3, Header:=xlYes`

**Note,** *This VB code will delete all rows from List 2 which has duplicate 
           Mail ID in Column 3.*

**N.B.** *Adjust cell references in formula & VB code as needed.*